# ASP.Net Post-back Breaks jQuery FancyBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I have a FancyBox help link, on an ASP.Net aspx page, that is registered as such:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#help").fancybox({
            'width': '90%',
            'height': '90%',
            'autoScale': true,
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'titleShow': false,
            'type': 'iframe'
        });

    });
  </script>
```

It works fine, but after 2 post backs (still works after 1) an exeption is thrown here (in fancybox.js) saying 'wrap' is not an object, when I click the help link:

```
    $.fancybox.center = function() {
    var view, align;

    if (busy) {
        return; 
    }

    align = arguments[0] === true ? 1 : 0;
    view = _get_viewport();

    if (!align && (wrap.width() > view[0] || wrap.height() > view[1])) {
        return; 
    }
```

After the third post back, an error is thrown before the page is completely loaded within the jquery.js file `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method` pointing no where in peticular.

Any ideas why post backs would be breaking fancybox?

Comment: Where is wrap being defined? I think we need just a little more code. Perhaps the relavent HTML bits, and also some more info on wrap, and where it is being declared, set, etc...

Comment: Agreed on @Josh's request for more code - specifically, it would be very helpful to know if you're using update panels, and if so, are you properly handling client side PageRequestManager events to reregister your behaviors on request completion?

Comment: @Brian, I am not using update panels, should I be? It's just a regular `<a id="help">Help</a>` link, not sure why the post back is breaking it.

Comment: @Josh - wrap is defined in the fancybox.js file, It is rather large, so I dont think I should post it in my question.

Comment: @Petey B - you don't need update panels unless you're trying to use ASP.NET Ajax.  I asked because a lot of developers use them and forget that elements/nodes they attach to become undefined when the update panel refreshes.  Whether or not you should use update panels really depends on what you want to make and what your skillset is ...  if you're more of a C# guy than a javascript guy, using update panels will simplify your life but you'll take a performance hit if you're not careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is add "lazy_loader".

This will load your fancybox classes in each postback

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(lazy_loader);
        lazy_loader();
    });

    function lazy_loader() {
        $("#help").fancybox({
            'width': '90%',
            'height': '90%',
            'autoScale': true,
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'titleShow': false,
            'type': 'iframe'
        });
    }
</script>
```

This should work just fine